# Determine model instance from file URL

Tags: django, url-routing, filefield

Given the URL in the request is for a known static file, how can I determine **which model instance references that file**?

If I have several different Django model each with an `ImageField`, those fields each know how to store a relative path on the filesystem:

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Lorem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    secret_icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='secrets')
    secret_banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='secrets')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    secret_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='secrets')
```

Templates can then render those images, using (for example) the `instance.secret_banner.url` attribute.

When a request comes in for that same URL, I want to handle the request in a view:

```py
# urls.py

from django.urls import path

from .views import StaticImageView

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'secrets/<path:relpath>', StaticImageView.as_view(), name='static-image'),
]
```

So the `StaticImageView.get` method will be passed the `relpath` parameter parsed from the URL.

At that point I need to do more handling based on *which instance* made the URL for this static image.

```
# views.py

from django.views.generic import View

class StaticImageView(View):

    def get(self, request, relpath):
        instance = figure_out_the_model_instance_from_url_relpath(relpath)
        do_more_with(instance)
```

What I don't know is how to write that `figure_out_the_model_instance_from_url_relpath` code.

How can I **use that path to find which model and which instance, generated that URL**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query and get the instance from image file or rather the file name of the image.
First get the just filename of from the `relpath` and then query for the instance.

A sample code example:

```
class StaticImageView(View):

    def get(self, request, relpath):
        fname = get_filename_from_relpath(relpath)
        instance = Lorem.objects.get(secret_icon=fname)
        
        do_more_with_instance(instance)
```

I assumed you want to get based on `secret_icon` image. You can change it as required.

Comment: Can you edit to show why `get_filename_from_relpath` would be needed? Is `relpath` not already what will match?

Comment: @bignose You could see what path you are getting there and depending upon that you may need it or not. I don't have such setup so can't verify. Idea was to provide high level solution!